# Remove current url path and replace?

Tags: jquery

How do i delete the current url path and return to index.php? I have a link to a page in a subfolder - the generated url could look like this:

```
http://localhost/site/pages/home.php
```

How do i erase that url path and return to index.php in root `http://localhost/site/index.php`

So far i have this which will show index.php in root, but it doesnt delete the original url path containing home-php?

```
$('#btn').click(function() {    
   window.location.href='index.php';
});
```

The url looks like this `http://localhost/site/pages/home.php/site/index.php`

Comment: `window.location.href='/index.php';`

Comment: Are you talking about just showing the URL or also redirecting?

Comment: Yes - redirecting to index.php from ../pages/hone.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reload the page and redirect the user to the good page :

```
window.location.href='/index.php';
```

**EDIT :**

Or try to rebuild your url :

```
// If URL is http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top

window.location.pathname // /account/search

// For reference:

window.location.host     // www.somedomain.com (includes port if there is one)
window.location.hostname // www.somedomain.com
window.location.hash     // #top
window.location.href     // http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top
window.location.port     // (empty string)
window.location.protocol // http:
window.location.search   // ?filter=a
```

And redirect with the full url, not just/index.php

Comment: I already have that - i need to remove the 'old' url before using that bit